# Scope of nested function declarations

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, scope, closures

I have the following code:

```
def function_reader(path):
    line_no = 0 
    with open(path, "r") as myfile:
        def readline():
            line_no +=1
            return myfile.readline()
```

Python keeps returning:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line_no' referenced before assignment

when executing `line_no +=1`.

I understand that the problem is that nested function declarations have weird scoping in python (though I do not understand why it was programmed this way). I'm mostly wondering if there is a simple way to help python resolve the reference, since I really like the functionality this would provide.

Comment: It's working in Python 3.4

Comment: @sacma: Did you actually call `readline()`?

Comment: No, this isn’t possible (at all!) in Python 2. In Python 3, it’s easy: `nonlocal line_no`. (Use Python 3 if you can.)

Comment: This problem is actually [documented in the FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value), but alas, you need to use the `nonlocal` keyword that wasn't introduced until Python 3.

Comment: And what exactly you're trying to do here? I'd use a class here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this in Python 2.x.  Nested functions can only read names in the enclosing function, not reassign them.

One workaround would be to make `line_no` a list and then alter its single item:

```
def function_reader(path):
    line_no = [0]
    with open(path, "r") as myfile:
        def readline():
            line_no[0] += 1
            return myfile.readline()
```

You would then access the line number via `line_no[0]`.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def outer():
...     data = [0]
...     def inner():
...        data[0] += 1
...     inner()
...     return data[0]
...
>>> outer()
1
>>>
```

This solution works because we are not reassigning the name `line_no`, only mutating the object that it references.

---

Note that in Python 3.x, this problem would be easily solved using the [`nonlocal` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal_stmt):

```
def function_reader(path):
    line_no = 0
    with open(path, "r") as myfile:
        def readline():
            nonlocal line_no
            line_no += 1
            return myfile.readline()
```

Comment: `nonlocal` actually equal to `global` in some cases right? Or they are doing the same thing in some points. The difference is `global` variables can changeable by outside of function, `nonlocal` not. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  `global` is for names in the `global` namespace (outside all functions) where as `nonlocal` is for names in enclosing functions.  Both are scope declarations through.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what you're trying to achieve here by using closures. But the problem is that with this approach either you'll end with an `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` when you return `readline` from the outer function or just the first line if you return `readline()` from the outer function.

If all you wanted to do is call `readline()` repeatedly or loop over the file and also remember the current line number then better use a class:

```
class FileReader(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.line_no = 0
        self.file = open(path)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
       return self

    def next(self):
        line = next(self.file)
        self.line_no += 1
        return line

    def readline(self):
        return next(self)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.file.close()
```

**Usage:**

```
with FileReader('file.txt') as f:
    print next(f)
    print next(f)
    print f.readline()
    print f.line_no # prints 3
    for _ in xrange(3):
        print f.readline() 
    print f.line_no # prints 6
    for line in f:
        print line
        break
    print f.line_no # prints 7
```

Comment: A class is overkill here since the file itself can iterate linewise. For keeping track of the current line number, all you need is enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

The more Pythonic way to get the next line and keep track of the line number is with the enumerate builtin:

```
with open(path, "r") as my file:
    for no, line in enumerate(myfile, start=1):
        # process line
```

This will work in all current Python versions.